# which free cms system should i use?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm doing this for non-profit for my friends and classmates, but i have no idea which free cms best fits my requirements, i have listed following what i needs:

i'm paying for the hosting plans, please also list what kind of hosting required linux or windows for the suggested cms, or any good hosting company suggestions, thanks all in advance:

1. multi-site management
2. user can choose either to have subdomain under like user.xxx.com or register  and use their own domain
3. every user created will have certain limit disk space and bandwidth (so no over-usage)
4. front end layout (PREFER SOMETHING LIKE IMPRESSPAGES) and content "drag and drop" editing (very important)
5. advertisement management (able to set up google ads for all sites)
6. themes/skins (be able to manage themes/skins available for all sites at once)
7. site add-ons and functions (should be able to add once for all sites)
8. has a site setup function for the users, like when they starting, there is front end start up with themes to choose from.

Already took a quick look at:

1) express engine: they have a fee for every additional site installed, no point for me since i'm doing all these for free

2) dotcms: don't see front end drag and drop for theme layouts

3) wordpress: took a look at front-end editor, they have to go into admin to drag and drop, i would prefer front-end

4) opencms: front-end drag and drop is okay, desire a better one

Thanks all in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a lot of the factors determining what makes software great are subjective, I won't say one piece of software is definitively better than all the rest. However, I use and develop for **WordPress** on a daily basis. So, let's examine that one.

Here's how it stacks up against your list:

1. **Yes** - multi-site management
2. **Yes** - user can choose either to have subdomain under like user.xxx.com or register and use their own domain
3. **Yes** - every user created will have certain limit disk space and bandwidth (so no over-usage)
4. **Yes ( no native support for this, there are themes available )** - front end layout and content "drag and drop" editing (very important)
5. **Yes ( again, no native support, but there are plugins for this )** - advertisement management (able to set up google ads for all sites)
6. **Yes** - themes/skins (be able to manage themes/skins available for all sites at once)
7. **Yes** - site add-ons and functions (should be able to add once for all sites)
8. **They would need to be registered. Then they could choose from themes and such from the administration backend.** - has a site setup function for the users, like when they starting, there is front end start up with themes to choose from.

**Regarding hosting/platform:**

You can run **WordPress** on Linux, Windows, OSX, and anything else that will run **PHP** and MySQL. You can find a list of recommended hosting providers [here](http://wordpress.org/hosting/).

The solutions above are paths well trodden. Personally, I think you would get the most bang for your buck running on [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/). You can easily deploy **WordPress** from their Websites App Gallery and host it in a Website role ( pricing list [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/) ) for free with a free MySQL database ( automatically deployed for you ) from [ClearDB](http://www.cleardb.com/). Since you need custom domains, you'll actually have to upgrade the Website role to the Shared plan ( $9.36/mo ).

[Here's](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-from-gallery/) a tutorial on installing **WordPress** from the Azure Gallery.

**Note:**
This is a cheap and reliable way to get started. However, I personally wouldn't run this configuration since it's slow and restrictive from a performance ( and database size ) perspective. For about $10 more a month ( the cost of the MSSQL database ) and a bit more elbow grease ( just uploading some files via FTP ), you could drastically increase your performance by running a native install of **WordPress** on MSSQL.

**See:** [Project Nami](http://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami)

Whatever route you decide to go, best of luck to you! :)

Comment: can wordpress front end editor work something like "impresspages"?

Comment: I haven't used **ImpressPages**. So, I can't really say with a high degree of accuracy whether or not you'll get similar functionality. Look into PageLines for starters: http://pagelines.com

Comment: thanks, i think i'm going with wordpress, lots of plug-ins and recent security updates.

Comment: after i did some more research, i posted another thread if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828523/multisite-cms-comparison-cons-and-pros

Comment: I'm not sure there is a significant enough difference between that question and the one you've posted here to warrant a different answer. I would still use WordPress.

Comment: Thanks, it just that i searched more, and more stuff came up lol